# How can I pop or filter a nested dictionary based on keys and values in a list?

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to create a subset dictionary based on values in a list and not sure the best way to go about it.

I have a dictionary that is set up like this:

```
animal_dict = {'dog': {'color': {'white': 10,
                                 'yellow': 20,
                                 'brown': 30},
                      'attributes': {'legs': 4, 
                                     'teeth': 42}},
               'cat': {'color': {'white': 8,
                                   'calico': 10,
                                   'yellow': 12},
                      'attributes': {'legs': 4, 
                                     'teeth': 30}}
              }
```

.. and I have some key values of the items that i would like to keep:

```
keep_animal = ['dog']
keep_color = ['white', 'yellow']
```

My intended results would look like:

```
{'dog': {'color': {'white': 10,
                   'yellow': 20},
         'attributes': {'legs': 4, 
                        'teeth': 42}}}
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do reverse and instead of keeping you drop any parent keys you do not need.

```py
unwanted_parent_keys = ['cat', 'brown']
def keep_key(input_dict, drop_keys):
    new_dict = {}
    for k, v in input_dict.items():
        if k in drop_keys:
            continue
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            new_dict[k] = keep_key(v, drop_keys)
        else:
            new_dict[k] = v
    return new_dict

new_animal_dict = keep_key(animal_dict, unwanted_parent_keys)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution. The main reason I didn't start with removing the unwanteds is that in the real application there will be substantially (100s) more unwanted_parent_keys than wanted.  Though, I can easily adapt your solution to my issue by finding the UNwanteds given the wanteds.